# Debian cant find file but ls shows the file

Tags: mysql, linux, ssh, ext3, fsck

my MySQL Server doesnt starts because a file is missing.

The funny thing is that the file is visible for `ls -al` but other commands cant find the file.

[image: ls -al shows the files]

And thats the error.
A few files works.

[image: stat cant find the file or directory]

If i use `shutdown -rF now` to check the filesystem i get no error.

Whats the problem? :(

```
Filesystem: EXT3
Debian version: 6.0.10
```

[image: Some informations about the disk]

Comment: verify that *all* your partitions are checked i.e. sda1 and sda5 '$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/your-partition |grep "Last checked"' Because shutdown -rF sometimes didn't work for me at debian.

Comment: sda1: Mon Aug 4 10:29:52 2014 / sda2: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read (at the try to open /dev/sda2) Cant find a valid Filesystem-Superblock. / sda5: Bad magic number in super-block in try to open /dev/sda5 (no valid file system super block)

Comment: can you try mysqlbinlog binlog_name to see if the file is broken? Binlogs have the proper permissions? Did you tried to start without binlog enable?

Comment: Hmm with each dpkg --configure -a the /var/lib/mysql directory changes their owner to root/root -.-

Comment: Works @Anotnis. I disabled the binlog ^^

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the mysql binlog was the fix.

Thanks @Antonis